# Is this method of solving this differential inequality correct?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, solution-verification

If  $ P(1)=0 , and \frac{d(P(x)}{dx} >P(x),\forall x \geq 1$  , I have been asked to prove that $P(x)>0 ,\forall x\geq 1$

my attempt:-
$dx = \frac{dP(x)}{P(x)}$

$\int(dx) \geq \int{\frac{dP(x)}{P(x)}}$

$x+C \geq ln(P(x))$

so $e^{x+c} \geq P(x)$
and as $e^x$ is greater than zero, for all x, this inequality, must be true

my book solved this by multiplying both sides by $e^{-x}$, and then solving the ODE. Is my method right too, and if not, where is it wrong?

Comment: I think you got the right idea, however this isn't very rigorous. The derivative $P'(x)=\frac{dP(x)}{dx}$ is not a fraction. You cannot multiply by $dx$. Also you divided by $P(x)$ which could possibly be zero. Also you should use a definite integral from $1$ to $x$ to take advantage of $P(1)=0$.

Comment: I see, thanks. If I can't cross multiply, then how does I solve the ODE? for dx cannot be in the denominator while integrating, can it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to do the standard trick. We have $P'>P$.

Multiply both sides by $e^{-x}$ and get $e^{-x}P'(x)-P(x)e^{-x}>0$ then

$(e^{-x}P(x))'>0$ which gives $e^{-x}P(x)$ increasing.

So $e^{-x}P(x)>e^{-1}P(1)=0$ and $P(x)>0$ for $x>1$.

PS. Make a correction in your question. For $x=1$ , $P(1)=0$ so the statement is true for $x>1$.

Comment: Thanks! we can multiply this my any monotonic function in reality though, rght?

Comment: The standard integrating factor is of the form $e^{-ax}$.

Comment: oh yes, thanks!